# Implementing Peer to Peer payments

Tags: paypal, applepay, google-pay, venmo, samsung-pay

I am going to work on donation based app, where I need to do P2P payments as per the following scenario:

- UserA wants to send a amount from any of these payment methods Paypal, Venmo, Apple Pay, Google Pay, Samsung Pay etc to UserB.
- In our case, we need to send 100% amount to admin first and then from admin after deduction of commission, amount will then needs to be transferred to UserB.

I researched and found that, I can use Braintree which will accept payments from any of these methods but Braintree doesn't support payout option..

So I thought, we can do in this custom way:
- UserA chooses any of payment methods e.g. Paypal, then I need to send this amount to Admin and to UserB in their Paypal account. I found Paypal has a payout option for it, so we can transfer the amount from admin's paypal account to userB paypal account.

But for other methods, still I have not found any solution. Kindly suggest some approach for it.

Comment: I am looking for the PayPal option. you said you found an option for P2P for paypal, can you share some code? because I know paypal api v2 very well, but i am still a bit lost, because paypal has trouble naming their API correctly.

Answer (score 2):

To do that, you need to operate on the payment processing layer, that is, using services like as PayPal or payment gateways (like Braintree, Stripe, etc). Both Braintree (through [Marketplace](https://www.braintreepayments.com/es/products/braintree-marketplace)) and Stripe (with [Connect](https://stripe.com/en-es/connect)) can help you fulfill the use case described<sup>1</sup>.

Payment facilitators like Google Pay, Samsung Pay, Apple Pay or others do not process payments as off today, that is, you can use them on top of your payment processor to offer more convenient checkout experiences, but the actual exchange of funds will take place through your payment processor.

<sup>1<sub>: There are other marketplace-like alternatives –that I'm not familiar with. This [quora answer](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-good-alternative-to-Stripe-Connect-Marketplace) could be a good starting point.</sub></sup>